# problem with compiling .mm file

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I am trying to load .mm file on my **main.m** iPhone project  but i'v got some errors !!! I don't know how can i solve them ! these errors runs fine on the another .mm file !

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That file looks fine. I'd guess the error is in the .h - probably a missing ';'